# Creating a Table out of a While Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make a table from a while loop. Basically, I want to make a while loop where the value of r increases by 1 and repeats this until the inequality is met. But in addition to that, I want to combine these values into a table with three columns: the value of r, the value of w, and the value of rhs (rounded to 3 decimal places).

````
```{r}
al = 0.10; n = 30; a = 3; b = 5; r = 2; int = 8; h = (int/2); msE = 19.19
table = function(MSE, V, H, alpha = al, r = 2){
  rhs = h^2*r/((V-1)*MSE)
  w = qf(alpha, V-1, V*(r-1), lower.tail = FALSE)
  g = data.frame(r, round(w, 3), round(rhs, 3))
  while(w > rhs){
    r = r+1
    rhs = h^2*r/((V-1)*MSE)
    w = qf(alpha, V-1, V*(r-1), lower.tail = FALSE)
    g = data.frame(r, round(w, 3), round(rhs, 3))
  }
  rbind(g)
}
table(MSE = msE, V = a*b, H = h)
```
````

I figured it would go something like this, but this only prints out the last value of r before the loop ends (it ends at 26), which results in a "table" that only has one row. I would like a table with 24 rows (since it starts at r = 2).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `table()` is an existing R function and it's probably not a good idea to redefine it, rather choose a different name

Comment: Good call, I will rename it to something else (the name is trivial, after all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might help:

```
al = 0.10; n = 30; a = 3; b = 5; r = 2; int = 8; h = (int/2); msE = 19.19
table = function(MSE, V, H, alpha = al, r = 2){
  rhs = h^2*r/((V-1)*MSE)
  w = qf(alpha, V-1, V*(r-1), lower.tail = FALSE)
  g = data.frame(r, round(w, 3), round(rhs, 3))
  gn = data.frame(r, round(w, 3), round(rhs, 3))
  while(w > rhs){
    r = r+1
    rhs = h^2*r/((V-1)*MSE)
    w = qf(alpha, V-1, V*(r-1), lower.tail = FALSE)
    g = data.frame(r, round(w, 3), round(rhs, 3))
    gn <- rbind(gn,g)
  }
return(gn)
}
table(MSE = msE, V = a*b, H = h)
```

Comment: You might want to explain what makes your version work, in contrast to the OP's initial attempt

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, eliminating the need for an interim data frame and for `rbind()`. Commented in the code.

```
# your parameters
al <- 0.10; n <- 30; a <- 3; b <- 5; int <- 8; h <- (int/2); msE <- 19.19

# your function definition (name changed to avoid confusion / conflict with existing R function)
tabula <- function(MSE, V, H, alpha = al, r = 2)
{
    g <- data.frame( N = 0, W = 1, RHS = 0 )        # initiate data frame, values set
                                                    # so that the while condition is met

    # the while function populates the data frame cell by cell,
    # eliminating the need for an interim data.frame and rbind()
    while( g[ r - 1, "W" ] > g[ r - 1, "RHS" ] )    # check condition in the last data frame row
    {                                               # write values in a new row
        g[ r, "N" ] <- r
        g[ r, "W" ] <- round( qf( alpha, V - 1, V * ( r - 1 ), lower.tail = FALSE ), 3 )
        g[ r, "RHS" ] <- round( h^2 * r / ( ( V - 1 ) * MSE ), 3 )
        r <- r + 1                                  # increment row counter
    }
    return( g[ -1, ] )                              # return the data frame, removing the initial row
}

tabula( MSE = msE, V = a * b, H = h )
```